# Service failed to start because ernvironment variable is missing

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I am trying to start Geoserver as a systemd service using this script:

(using ubuntu 16.04)

```
[Unit]
Description=Geoserver
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ermis/geoserver/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/home/ermis/geoserver/bin/shutdown.sh
User=ermis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I get this error in syslog

```
systemd[1]: Starting Geoserver...    
startup.sh[21823]: The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined
    systemd[1]: geoserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    startup.sh[21823]: This environment variable is needed to run this program
    startup.sh[21823]: Please set it to the directory where geoserver was installed
    VM2 systemd[1]: geoserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    VM2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Geoserver.
```

I tried to enter GEOSERVER_HOME in /etc/environment but I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an environment file to your service definition:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/yourservice
```

Then create that file (the actual path is up to you) and define your variable there and reload your service definitions:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now the environment variables should be used by your service.

Comment: Thanks, could this file be /etc/environment which exists already?

Comment: I don't see why not. This will however define the variable for every user on the system. This is usually not what people want.

Comment: OK, I created the environment file in `/home/ermis/geoserver/env` with the GEOSERVER_HOME var and added this line in the `geoserver.service` file: `EnvironmentFile=/home/ermis/geoserver/env` under Service section. I still get the same error

Comment: I rebooted the server. It works. Thanks